# Sublime Text 2 IntelliSense - How to?

Tags: sublime-text-2

I would like to plug IntelliSense-like functionality into Sublime Text 2. Is there a package that does this?

Comment: Sublime has autocompletion already and there's no IntelliSense package. What specific functionality do you need?

Comment: Well, for starters, I would like to have autocompletion on javascript functions. Once a function has been declared, it should recognize it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no 1:1 clone of IntelliSense. But maybe [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel) suits your needs?

> Provides the following features:
>
> - Jump to Symbol Definition - Jump to the file and line of the definition of a symbol.
> - Imports autocomplete - Shows autocomplete with the available modules/symbols in real time.
> - Function Call tooltips - Displays information in the status bar about the working function.

It can be easily installed via [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control). Don't forget to restart Sublime after the installation. See the GitHub page for a README.

Comment: this package suck. it doesnt work 90% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a package which enables auto-completion, it's called [SublimeClang](https://github.com/quarnster/SublimeClang) and uses the llvm/clang framework. In addition it supports the static-analysis tools from clang.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit delayed answer, but hopefully someone will find this plugin useful.

**JavaScript-API-Completions**

https://github.com/Pleasurazy/Sublime-JavaScript-API-Completions